# How to separate function call from this function

Tags: python, function, import

I have an existing script that contains functions that I would like to call from another script. I would like to modify it such that the `main` function does not automatically call the `primitives` function.

The full script reads:

```
import time
import datetime
from luma.core.render import canvas


def primitives1(device, draw):
    # First define some constants to allow easy resizing of shapes.
    padding = 2
    shape_width = 20 
    top = padding
    bottom = device.height - padding - 1
    # Move left to right keeping track of the current x position for drawing shapes.
    x = padding
    # Write two lines of text.
    size = draw.textsize('World!')
    x = device.width - padding - size[0]
    draw.rectangle((x, top + 4, x + size[0], top + size[1]), fill="black")
    draw.rectangle((x, top + 16, x + size[0], top + 16 + size[1]), fill="black")
    draw.text((device.width - padding - size[0], top + 4), 'Hello', fill="cyan") 
    draw.text((device.width - padding - size[0], top + 16), 'World!', fill="purple") 
    time.sleep(5)

    def primitives2(device, draw):
    # First define some constants to allow easy resizing of shapes.
    padding = 2
    shape_width = 20 
    top = padding
    bottom = device.height - padding - 1
    # Move left to right keeping track of the current x position for drawing shapes.
    x = padding

    # Write two lines of text.
    size = draw.textsize('World!')
    x = device.width - padding - size[0]
    draw.rectangle((x, top + 4, x + size[0], top + size[1]), fill="black")
    draw.rectangle((x, top + 16, x + size[0], top + 16 + size[1]), fill="black")
    draw.text((device.width - padding - size[0], top + 4), 'Bye', fill="cyan") 
    draw.text((device.width - padding - size[0], top + 16), 'Bye!', fill="purple") 
    time.sleep(5)    

def main():
    from luma.core.interface.serial import spi
    from luma.core.render import canvas
    from luma.oled.device import ssd1351
    serial = spi(device=0, port=0, gpio_DC=20)
    device = ssd1351(serial)
    device.width=128
    device.height=128
    print("Testing basic canvas graphics...")
    for _ in range(2):
        with canvas(device) as draw:
            primitives1(device, draw)
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Testing clear display...")
    time.sleep(1)
    device.clear()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

Is there a way that I can remove `primitives1(device, draw)` from `def main` but still retain the `with canvas(device) as draw:`? If I leave `with canvas(device) as draw:` there without calling `primitives1`, terminal will print an error if I try to launch the script.

The reason that I want to do this is so that I can use another script to call `main()` first and then choose to call either `primitives1` or `primitives2`.

Comment: You can comment out `primitives1(device, draw)` and put in `pass` but I'm still not sure I see why you can't comment out the entire `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks bivouac0, that resolves the error. However, in my other script (`script2.py`) where I used: `from script1 import primitives1, main
  main()
  primitives1(device, draw)` at the line where I call `primitives1`, I got an error saying that `draw` is not defined.

Comment: Why did I get that error when I already called `main()` which has `with canvas(device) as draw:`

Comment: Because `draw` isn't a global, it's defined inside your function.  I would do one of the following... 1- pass the primativeX function you want to use to main like... `main(prim_func)` and then use that name under the `with canvas(` or 2- return `device` from `main` and put the `with canvas(...` in your script.

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure what you mean with 1. What I made are these changes including `def main(x):` as well as `with canvas(device) as draw:
            x ` to script1 and in the other script, I did: `main(primitives1(device, draw))`. Is that what I should do? I'm still getting the draw is not defined error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would modify the main function to take in the primitivesX function definition.  You want to use like this...

```
def main(prim_func):
    ...
    for _ in range(2):
        with canvas(device) as draw:
            prim_func(device, draw)
```

You would then call main something like...

```
main(primitives1) 
or...
main(primatives2)
```

Note that your passing in the declared name of the function, not an instance of it.  Of course, be sure that the name is defined somewhere in your script or imported.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me! So this method allows the secondary function to become an argument of a primary function. That allows the arguments of the secondary function to stay put and avoids the `name not defined` error.